# Java Elegant splitting String by array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, split

Have you any idea about elegant splitting input String by String Array?

For example:

1. We have splitter array with String elements

   > ["=","!=","<=",">=","<",">"]
2. We have an expression

   > "44+22<=x+y>=2x+4r>34"

The result should be:

> ["44+22","x+y", "2x+4r","34"]

Comment: [`String::split(...)` takes a regex as argument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). So the only challenge would be to transform the `String[]` into a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex, `(\\<\\=)|(\\>\\=)|(\\>)` where `|` is used as `or`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String exp = "44+22<=x+y>=2x+4r>34";
        String[] arr = exp.split("(\\<\\=)|(\\>\\=)|(\\>)");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[44+22, x+y, 2x+4r, 34]
```